# how can I use sympy to solve system of equations with constraint conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, equation

the example like this:

```
    x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 1
    x3 + x4 = 1
    x4 + x5 = 1
    x4 + x5 + x6 = 2
    x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 belong to this set {0, 1}
```

so you see, it's a **linear system of equations.**

because x belongs to {0,1} <--> x**2 - x = 0
so I solve this below...but I think it's so foolish:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from sympy import *

In [3]: x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 = symbols('x:6')

In [4]: res = solve([x1+x2+x3+x4-1, x3+x4-1, x4+x5-1, x4+x5+x6-2, x1**2-x1, x5**2-x5, x2**2-x2, x3**2-x3, x4**2-x4, x5*
   ...: *2-x5, x6**2-x6],[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6])

In [5]: np.array(res)
Out[5]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=object)
```

I know var can be added some constraint conditions:

```
x = Symbol("x", positive=True)
```

**so, is there some constraint conditions can be added like this?**:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6 = symbols('x:6', domain=(0, 1))
```

Help me out, plz..thank you!

Comment: to clarify: your domain is the open segment (0,1), the closed segment [0,1] or the integers: 0 and 1?

Comment: You are dealing with an integer (binary) linear program. Sympy is highly inefficient for this task. You should use a numerical package/library such as cvxpy

Comment: @YakovDan oops...integer 0 and 1

Comment: How big are your instances? Do you typically have a few equations with a few variables or can you have tens and hundreds of equations with tens or hundreds of variables?

Comment: @YakovDan thank you for your

Comment: @YakovDan thank you for your comments. the number of equations maybe about 4,5 and variables maybe about 8,9 or more, one loop in my program. to run this program maybe loop 200+ times, but no more than 500. I want to improve my program performance...but I am not familiar with sympy. Just like  use x**2 - x = 0 to imply the variable x is integer 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simpy, you may use the scipy.optimize.least_squares package:

scipy.optimize.least_squares(fun, x0, jac='2-point', bounds=(- inf, inf), method='trf', ftol=1e-08, xtol=1e-08, gtol=1e-08, x_scale=1.0, loss='linear', f_scale=1.0, diff_step=None, tr_solver=None, tr_options={}, jac_sparsity=None, max_nfev=None, verbose=0, args=(), kwargs={})

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares

First, you need to create the function for the argument *fun* and then should pass it to the solver in the following form:

```
      def fun(x0):
         return f(x0) ## f is your cost_function, any function of x0
```

Then, you need to create a NumPy array x0 = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6] (x1=x0[0], and so on..).
Then you need to provide the bound for each variable on the *bounds=(- inf, inf)* argument. Lower and upper bounds on independent variables. Defaults to no bounds. Each array must match the size of x0 or be a scalar.

To address your particular problem of yours, hope the following code might be helpful. I create the A and b from the equations and thus:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def fun_EM(x0):
    retrun_array = []
    for row_id,t_row in enumerate(A):
        cur_b = b[row_id][0]
        equ_temp= 0
        for col_id,item in enumerate(t_row):
            equ_temp = equ_temp + item * x0[col_id]
        retrun_array.append(equ_temp - cur_b)
    #print(retrun_array)
    return np.array(retrun_array)

A = np.array([[1,1,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1,1]])
b = np.array([[1,1,1,2]]).T
x0 = np.zeros(6).T ## initialization
res_ = least_squares(fun_EM, x0,bounds=(0,1))
```

I found the following solution:

```
res_.x = array([1.36927447e-10, 1.36927447e-10, 1.73854895e-10, 2.84637236e-10,2.10782342e-10, 1.73854895e-10])
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

I use linsolve to solve the linear equations without limiting the domain. Then, the solution set maybe empty, fully determined or dependent on some free variables. I then try every substitution for the free variables from {0,1} and collect only those that result in a solution such that every variable is in {0,1}.

```
from sympy import *

def eval_solution(concrete_solution):
    concrete_solution_eval = list(map(lambda x: x == 1 or x == 0,concrete_solution))
    if sum(concrete_solution_eval) == len(concrete_solution):
        return True

    return False

def enumerate_solutions(Sols):

    if Sols.free_symbols == set(): # no free variables. see if all variables belong to {0,1}

        concrete_solution = Sols.args[0]
        if concrete_solution == set(): # no solutions
            return []
        if eval_solution(concrete_solution):
            return [concrete_solution]
        else:
            return []
    # create a list of tuples of free variables, one for each valid value
    free_vars = []
    for i in range(2**len(Sols.free_symbols)):
        free_vars.append(tuple(Sols.free_symbols))

    # generate values to substitute for free variables
    free_vals = [list(bin(i))[2:] for i in range(2**len(Sols.free_symbols))] 
    free_vals = [tuple(map(int, list('0'*(len(Sols.free_symbols)-len(s)))+s )) for s in free_vals] 

    # zip twice to generate lists of pairs of variable and value
    free_zip = zip(free_vars,free_vals)
    free_zip_fin = list([list( zip( x[0], x[1] )) for x in free_zip ] )

    correct_solutions = []

    for substitution in free_zip_fin:
        concrete_solution = list(map(lambda x: x.subs(substitution),Sols.args[0]))
        if eval_solution(concrete_solution):
            correct_solutions.append(concrete_solution)

    return correct_solutions

x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 = symbols('x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6')

res=linsolve([x1+x2+x3+x4-1, x3+x4-1, x4+x5-1, x4+x5+x6-2],[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6])

l = enumerate_solutions(res)

print (l)
```

This may or may not be faster than your idea. See for yourself if this is of any use to you