# how to work with equations with mathematical constraints on variables in sympy

Tags: sympy

I try to simplify and solve equations using sympy with mathematical constraints. I didn't find in tutorials in the net how to inform sympy to take into account for those constraints.

I have an example equation (see next code) and I want sympy to take into account for the listed constraints on these variables when working on it. But i didn't succeed to find how to inform sympy about those [constraints (limitations / boundaries).](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/LinearEquations/LEconstraints.html)

```
import sympy
D1,D2,D3,A,B,C,d,e,f = sympy.symbols('D1 D2 D3 A B C d e f')
equation = (-A*e + e*(A*d + (1.0 - d)*(D1 + 0.5*D2 + 0.5*D3)) + (1.0 - e)*( D1*d - D1 + 0.5*D2*d - 0.5*D2 + 0.5*D3*d - 0.5*D3 + A**2*(1.0 - d) + 0.5*A*B*(2.0 - 2.0*d) + 0.5*A*C*(2.0 - 2.0*d)))**2

#constraints: my trouble: how to take them into account in simplify, collect, solve?
A+B+C=1
D1+0.5*D2+0.5D3 = f
0.<=D1,D2,D3,A,B,C,d,e,f<=1.

print(sympy.latex(sympy.collect(equation,[f,A]))
```

thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: It isn't possible to set global constraints. How you can apply constraints depends on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959174/assuming-a-symbol-is-between-zero-and-one-with-sympy) when assuming inequalities. And then for the equality constraints, you could solve for `B` and solve for `D1` respectively and substitute their solutions into `equation`.

Comment: You may find this discussion helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814074/how-can-i-use-sympy-to-solve-system-of-equations-with-constraint-conditions/73066202#73066202